# Json Schema: Verifying a type based on where it is used

Tags: jsonschema

I'd like to define a schema with a type whose required set differs based on where it's used.

Simple example, we have a `letter` which contains a `sender` and `recipient`, which are very similar objects. The naive solution would be to just define distinct types for them:

```js
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type":"object",
    "definitions":{
        "sender":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "zipCode":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "isDomestic" : { 
                    "type" : "boolean"
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "zipCode"
            ]
        },
        "recipient":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "zipCode":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "isDomestic" : { 
                    "type" : "boolean"
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "zipCode",
                "isDomestic"
            ]
        }
    },
    "properties":{
        "letter":{
            "type":"object",
            "required":[
                "sender",
                "recipient"
            ],
            "properties":{
                "sender":{
                    "$ref":"#/definitions/sender"
                },
                "recipient":{
                    "$ref":"#/definitions/recipient"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define this by merging the `sender` and `recipient` classes into one, and only requiring the `isDomestic` field if an address is used as a `recipient`?

*In case of XY questions: While duplicating the class over a minor difference is fine in this simple case, nesting can make that solution introduce a lot of code duplication (imagine a `letter` holding two `person` objects each with an  `address`, the only difference in the entire hierarchy being that one `address` contains a `senderZipCode` and the other a `receiverZipCode`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `allOf` keyword, and extracting the common elements into a new definition:

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type":"object",
    "definitions":{
        "sender_or_recipient": {
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "zipCode":{
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "isDomestic" : { 
                    "type" : "boolean"
                }
            },
            "required":[
                "zipCode"
            ]
        },
        "sender":{
            "$ref":"#/definitions/sender_or_recipient"
        },
        "recipient":{
            "allOf":[
                {
                    "$ref":"#/definitions/sender_or_recipient"
                },
                {
                    "required":[
                        "isDomestic"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "properties":{
        "letter":{
            "type":"object",
            "required":[
                "sender",
                "recipient"
            ],
            "properties":{
                "sender":{
                    "$ref":"#/definitions/sender"
                },
                "recipient":{
                    "$ref":"#/definitions/recipient"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```